# "Most Replayed" Data of YouTube Video via API

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to extract the "Most Replayed" (aka Video Activity Graph) Data from a YouTube video via API?

What I'm referring to:

[image: Image of Youtube Video with "Most Replayed" Data displayed]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I'm not sure how many more details I can give :/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/0ad9252a2fb7cbb510bc353ddf20108b31c8b3ba/videos.php#L283-L302) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=mostReplayed&id=VIDEO_ID, you will get the *most replayed* graph values you are looking for in `item["mostReplayed"]`.

With the video id [`XiCrniLQGYc`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiCrniLQGYc) you would get:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "XiCrniLQGYc",
            "mostReplayed": {
                "markers": [
                    {
                        "startMillis": 0,
                        "intensityScoreNormalized": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "startMillis": 2580,
                        "intensityScoreNormalized": 0.7083409245967562
                    },
                    {
                        "startMillis": 5160,
                        "intensityScoreNormalized": 0.6381007317793738
                    },
                    ...
                    {
                        "startMillis": 255420,
                        "intensityScoreNormalized": 0.012864077773078256
                    }
                ],
                "timedMarkerDecorations": [
                    {
                        "visibleTimeRangeStartMillis": 0,
                        "visibleTimeRangeEndMillis": 10320
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This looks like it works, but how should I read the page it spits out? For example: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/videos?part=mostReplayed&id=NIJ5RiMAmNs. How should I read that?

Comment: @prodohsamuel Look at the "heatMarkerIntensityScoreNormalized" number. 0 is nobody is re-playing and 1 is everybody is replaying.

Comment: @prodohsamuel As `heatMarkerIntensityScoreNormalized` name suggests, I recommend you to learn more about [Normalisation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)).

Comment: I have tried to use this API for finding the most replayed part from the top videos by generating the ID of YouTube's most trending videos using the `googleapiclient` but when I request the API, it returns the `item[mostReplayed]` as None. Am I doing something wrong with your API as it has worked very well with IDs that I have just manually retrieved from other YouTube videos.

Comment: [@CharlieCook](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15032918/charlie-cook) Please provide an example of video id having this issue.

Comment: I generated a list of the most trending videos' ids:

Comment: `['l-bGkjtMC0Q', 'OLvRv-poMtA', '4R7vRFGJr3k', 'OBsLKLef-F0', 'ar3gEAT2h28', '6ecTO22ulRM', 'J4-lP_D7iEk', 'ZEuV9d3gsio', 'T4CY4wVqhPU', 'v8tR7mPsBcU']`

Comment: @CharlieCook As [we discussed on Discord](https://discord.com/channels/933841502155706418/933841503103627316/1186340230723293265), your first video [`l-bGkjtMC0Q`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-bGkjtMC0Q) does not have public most replayed data (see [OP highlighted curve example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72610552)), hence my API cannot retrieve any.